# javascript:togglecomments need to add images + -

Tags: javascript

I am currently using the following to expand collapse divs

```
<style type="text/css"> 
   .commenthidden {display:none}
   .commentshown {display:inline}
    table.gridtable td { padding:15px;}
   .dropdowntitle a {color:#333; fontsize:13px; text-decoration: none;}
</style>
```

script

```
function togglecomments (postid) {
    var whichpost = document.getElementById(postid);

    if (whichpost.className=="commentshown") {
        whichpost.className="commenthidden"; 
    }  else {
       whichpost.className="commentshown"; 
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="commenthidden" id="Accelerators">
    <p>text here lalala</p>
    <p>but I need the image to change to the minus when the div is shown using this image http://i.microsoft.com/global/ImageStore/PublishingImages/icons/icon_plus_hover.png</p>
</div>
```

I want to add the `+` `-` signs so when a user clicks on the title the image changes to the minus image etc made alittle fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/YE5GF/

You assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you will not change your HTML structure, This is solution

**HTML**

```
<h4 class="dropdowntitle">
   <a href="#" onclick="togglecomments(this,'Accelerators')" aiotitle=""><img width="20" height="20" style="FLOAT: left; MARGIN: 0px 5px 0px 0px" alt="" src="http://i.microsoft.com/global/ImageStore/PublishingImages/icons/icon_plus.png" /> Read more details</a>
</h4>
```

**JS**

```
function togglecomments (that,postid) {
    var img =that.firstElementChild;
    var whichpost = document.getElementById(postid);

   if (whichpost.className=="commentshown") {
      whichpost.className="commenthidden";
      img.src='http://i.microsoft.com/global/ImageStore/PublishingImages/icons/icon_plus.png'; 
   } else { 
      whichpost.className="commentshown";
      img.src='http://i.microsoft.com/global/ImageStore/PublishingImages/icons/icon_plus_hover.png';
   }
}
```

Remove that `href="javascript://"` to inline function call `onclick`. Actually this is also is not best practice. When you will feel good with this, try to avoid inline call and do triggering in Javascript: `document.getElementById('forExample').onclick = function() {...`